# Multiple draggable modals or pop ups in angular

Tags: angular

Can anyone suggest how can i create multiple draggable modals or pop ups in angular, as angular material doesn't allow multiple modals,is there any other way of doing this

Comment: Material allows multiple modals, so can you tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов - i have created two simple modals, but they are overlapping each other, i can interact with other until and unless  i dn't close one, i need to  open like five separate modals and put the the functionality of dragging to it.

Comment: In the future please try providing more information about your question, about what have you tried so far, and if possible a stackblitz link with your problem, this will make your question better received by the community in general.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be that easy to start dragging dialogs, but opening multiple dialogs at different positions is an easy feat.

Here the key part is that you want to be able to drag those dialogs/elements around, for that purpose I would recommend you to use the material drag and drop module (as I see that you are using Material anyway).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.css']
})
export class CdkDragDropFreeDragPositionExample {
  dialogCoordiantes: { [key: number]: { x: number; y: number } } = {};
  activeDialogs: number[] = [];

  addDialog() {
    let dialogId = Math.random();
    this.activeDialogs.push(dialogId);
    this.dialogCoordiantes[dialogId] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0 - (this.activeDialogs.length - 1) * 190
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="addDialog()">Add Dialog</button>

<div style="max-height:0px; height:0px; position:fixed;">
  <mat-card
    *ngFor="let id of activeDialogs"
    cdkDrag
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dialogCoordiantes[id]"
    class="example-box"
  >
    Separate Dialog with id {{id}}
  </mat-card>
</div>

<h1>
  Here is an example of drag and drop, start clicking the add Dialog button
</h1>
```

By importing the drag and drop functionality, you will have access to the `cdkDrag` directive, which will make the elements over which it is attached draggable. If you want to specify or change the position of those draggable elements, you can use the `cdkDragFreeDragPosition`.

Here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-draggable-dialogs-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.ts) example.